# rails exporting csv in background

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activejob

I have made an csv importer and exporter in rails for article model.
It takes the articles and downloads it in the csv format.
It is working fine but I want it to be in a backgrond process.
Can anyone tell how to perform the import and export in background.

Here are my files which I have used-

```
Article_controller

  def index
    @articles = Article.all
    @articles = Article.includes(:user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @articles }
      format.atom
      @articles = Article.order(:name).page params[:page]
      format.csv { send_data @articles.to_csv, filename: "#{current_user.email}-#{Date.today}.csv" }

    end
  end
...
```

```
article.rb

def self.import(file,userid)
      user = User.find_by(id: userid)
      if user
        CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
        user.articles.create! row.to_hash
        end
      end
    end
  def self.to_csv
    attributes = %w{id title content}
    CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
      csv << attributes
      all.each do |article|
        csv << article.attributes.values_at(*attributes)
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Take a look at https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html and https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#starting-the-backend

Answer (score 1):

### Import:

The import is easier, because the users do not necessarily have to receive feedback after import is done.

As mentioned in the comments you can use [ActiveJob](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html) with a backend like [sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq):

You could use a background job in your article.rb:

```rb
def self.import(file, userid)
  CSVImportJob.perform_later(file.path, userid)
end

class CSVImportJob 
  def perform(filepath, userid)
    user = User.find_by(id: userid)
    if user
      CSV.foreach(filepath, headers: true) do |row|
        user.articles.create! row.to_hash
      end
    end
  end
end
```

### Export:

The export is trickier, because you cannot send a file to user from a background job. You can either poll the results from the browser or send a websocket notification with [ActionCable](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html)

The background processing would look similar to the import:

```rb
def self.export
  CSVExportJob.perform_later
end

class CSVExportJob 
  def perform
    attributes = %w{id title content}
    CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
      csv << attributes
      Article.find_each do |article|
        csv << article.attributes.values_at(*attributes)
      end
    end
    # Save CSV somewhere and notify its readiness
  end
end
```

Then you would have to create a different route for triggering the CSV creation.
And the ArticleController#index would always return the last exported CSV, that is saved somewhere in the DB or file system.

Answer (score -1):

To expand on Exporting, definitely use a job or Sidekiq worker to generate the CSV.

To inform the user when the job/worker is complete, use hotwire/turbo to broadcast an update and/or send an email.

When it comes to delivering a csv that was generated in a job/worker, [ActiveStorage](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#has-one-attached) makes it very easy:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :download, dependent: :delete_all
end
```

Then attach the csv string to the model like this:

```
class GenerateCsvJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(user_id)
    user = User.find(user_id)
    csv_string = ::CSV.generate do |csv| etc...
    user.download.attach(io: StringIO.new(csv_string), filename: "file.csv",content_type: "application/csv")
  end
end
```

And link to the download like this:

```
<%= link_to "Download", rails_blob_path(@user.download, disposition: :attachment), target: "_blank" %>
```